# Google Search Results/ Beginner Python

Tags: python

Just some questions regarding Python 3.

```
def AllMusic():
    myList1 = ["bob"]
    myList2 = ["dylan"]
    x = myList1[0]
    z = myList2[0]
    y = "-->Then 10 Numbers?"
    print("AllMusic")
    print("http://www.allmusic.com/artist/"+x+"-"+z+"-mn"+y)
```

This is my code so far.

I want to write a program that prints out the variable y.

When you go to AllMusic.com. The different artists have unique 10 numbers.

For example, www.allmusic.com/artist/the-beatles-mn0000754032‎, www.allmusic.com/artist/arcade-fire-mn0000185591.

x is the first word of the artist and y is the second word of the artist. Everything works but I can't figure out a way to find that 10 digit number and return it to me for each artist I input into my python program.

I figured out that when you go to google and type for example "Arcade Fire AllMusic", in the first result just under the heading it gives you the url of the site. www.allmusic.com/artist/arcade-fire-mn0000185591

How can I copy that 10 digit code, 0000185591, into my python program and print it out for me to see.

Comment: Do you have  already the URL with the number or you are thinking on going to internet and get that URL from there?

Comment: Exactly, I want to input artist names and have my program find the unique codes.

Comment: seems like you would maybe need to scrape the numbers from the site. I could imagine BeautifulSoup being of use here

Comment: You should search for  the API that will allow ask the web for the number given the names.

Comment: Beautiful Soup and API? Sorry kinda new to python and programming. And yes I just want to scrape the numbers after the mn part.

Comment: If I not wrong, you want to make a search on internet with the names and then retrieve the number. But that is not only a matter of  python, you should also know "how to" make the question to Allmusic.com.

Comment: What do you mean? I'm scraping from google not allmusic.

Comment: So, have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17561229/2397017

Comment: I'm just a noob practising and learning coding. I'm just curious and questioning things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't use Google at all - you can use the search on the site. There are many useful tools to help you do web scraping in python: I'd recommend installing [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/). Here's a small script you can experiment with:

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_artist_link(artist):
    base = 'http://www.allmusic.com/search/all/'
    # encode spaces                                                                 
    query = artist.replace(' ', '%20')
    url = base + query
    page = urllib.urlopen(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read())
    artists = soup.find_all("li", class_ = "artist")
    for artist in artists:
        print(artist.a.attrs['href'])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    get_artist_link('the beatles')
    get_artist_link('arcade fire')
```

For me this prints out:

```
/artist/the-beatles-mn0000754032
/artist/arcade-fire-mn0000185591
```

Comment: Thanks. What's the %20 there for?

Comment: You can't have spaces in a URL, so it's a way to encode that. For that and other special characters, see more here: [Percent-encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#Character_data). `urllib` has a builtin function [`urllib.quote_plus`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.quote_plus) to handle this as well.